# Filter a collection of objects to take an array of values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js

Actually the question is related to typeahead bootstrap
because I need to define an array of values to show in input text by using autocomplete.

Anyway, the goal is just to define a function which read an array of objects and return an array of string.
Here is my code(1).

The goal of (1) is:
1) get an array of strings from an array of objects.
2) filter this array rejecting some elements.

It does not work because the element I want to reject persists in the array.
In fact in the autocomplete I get false value, actually it brokes the code because false is not expected by typeahead.

How should fix the code and maybe improve it?

---

(1)

```
element.typeahead({
    source: function ( {
        var users = _.map(app.userCollection.models, function (model) {
            if (model.get('id') === app.currentUser.id) {
                return false;
            }
            return model.get('first_name') + ' ' + model.get('last_name');
        });
        console.log(users); // [false, 'some name'];
        _.reject(users, function(name) {
            return name  === false;
        });
        console.log(users); // [false, 'some name'];
                            // why does the false value persist?
        return users;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore methods don't usually operate on the array itself, but they return a new array, but I suggest checking the underscore [docs](http://underscorejs.org) on each function individually for confirmation. In this case we can safely assume that reject returns some new array, according to this sentence in the underscore [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#reject):

> Returns the values in list without the elements that the truth test (iterator) passes.

What you are currently doing is:

```
_.reject(users, function(name) {
  return name  === false;
});
```

So, you don't actually save your results anywhere. To preserve a reference to the array without the unwanted elements do this:

```
users = _.reject(users, function(name) {
  return name  === false;
});
```

That would yield the result you want, but let me give you a refactoring hint:

Use backbone's own methods as far as you can, it'll make for more readable code

```
source: function() {
  // filter the collection down to the users you want
  var users = app.userCollection.filter(function(model) {
    return model.id === app.currentUser.id;
  });
  // -> users is now an array of models

  // use map to transform each wanted user to a string giving its full name
  users = _.map(users, function(user) {
    return user.get('first_name')+' '+user.get('last_name');
  });
  // -> users is now an array of strings

  return users;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps, except I would like to get the models which `model.id !== app.currentUser.id;` and not `model.id === app.currentUser.id;`. Thanks a lot.